# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" on button click when incrementing numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, increment

## Problem

I have two buttons `.btn-previous` and `btn-next`. Clicking on one of the buttons either adds or subtracts one from the variable `var currentNumber = 0,`. But when a user clicks next all the way to the last person or clicks previous all the way to the first person in the array, I see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

**I've tried:**

- Switching the comparison operators in the if statements
- Isolating parts of the if statement that may be causing the problem,

`$(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name); 
$(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);`

## Objective

- As you click the next or previous button, change the name, description and the button text that contains the name of the next and previous person in the array
- If the user is at the end of the array, hide the next button, show previous
- If they are at the beginning of the array, hide the previous button, show next

### Here's a JSFiddle of the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xm96vw9/16/

### scripts.js

```
$(function(){

  var currentNumber = 0;

    // Key players
    // Sets the default values as the first key player
    $(".player__info--name").html(players[currentNumber].name);
    $(".player__info--desc").html(players[currentNumber].description);
    $(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);

    if (currentNumber <= 0) {
      $(".btn-previous").hide();
      $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "flex-end");
    } else {
      $(".btn-previous").show();
      $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "space-between");
    }

    // When a person clicks on the previous button
    $(".btn-previous").on("click", function() {

      if (currentNumber > 0) {
        currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;

        $(".btn-previous").show();
        $(".btn-next").show();
        $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "flex-end");
        $(".player__info--name").html(players[currentNumber].name);
        $(".player__info--desc").html(players[currentNumber].description);
        $(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name);
        $(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);
      } else {
        $(".btn-previous").hide();
        $(".btn-next").show();
        $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "space-between");
      }
    });

    // When a person clicks on the next button
    $(".btn-next").on("click", function() {


      // It's six because it's zero-indexed
      if (currentNumber < 6 ) {
        currentNumber = currentNumber + 1;
        console.log(currentNumber);

        $(".player__info--name").html(players[currentNumber].name);
        $(".player__info--desc").html(players[currentNumber].description);
        $(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name);
        $(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);

        $(".btn-previous").show();
        $(".btn-next").show();
        $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "flex-start");
      } else {
        $(".btn-previous").show();
        $(".btn-next").hide();
        $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "space-between");
      }
    });


  });


var players = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "description": "description1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "description": "description2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name3",
    "description": "description3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "name4",
    "description": "description4"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "name5",
    "description": "description5"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "name6",
    "description": "description6"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "name7",
    "description": "description7"
  }
]
```

### index.html

```
<div class="player__info">
    <div class="player__info--inner-group">
        <div class="player__image--wrapper">
            <div class="player__image"></div>
        </div> <!-- player__image--wrapper -->

        <div class="player__info--inner">
            <p class="player__info--header">Key Players</p>
            <p class="player__info--name">tk-name</p>

            <div class="player__info--group">
                <p class="player__info--desc"></p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- player__info--inner -->
    </div> <!-- player__info--inner-group -->
</div> <!-- player__info -->

<div class="controls">
    <div class="controls__inner">
        <button class="btn btn-previous">Previous: <span class="is-bold">tk-name</span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-next">Next: <span class="is-bold">tk-name</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So check to see if you are at the end. If you are, you either do not increment or you go back to the start. Same with the start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a check after you've updated your `currentNumber` and if it's at the end of your range, hide that button, otherwise update the text of that button.

```js
$(function() {

  var currentNumber = 0;

  // Key players
  // Sets the default values as the first key player
  $(".player__info--name").html(players[currentNumber].name);
  $(".player__info--desc").html(players[currentNumber].description);
  $(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);

  if (currentNumber <= 0) {
    $(".btn-previous").hide();
    $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "flex-end");
  } else {
    $(".btn-previous").show();
    $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "space-between");
  }

  // When a person clicks on the previous button
  $(".btn-previous").on("click", function() {

    currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;

    $(".btn-next").show();
    $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "flex-end");
    $(".player__info--name").html(players[currentNumber].name);
    $(".player__info--desc").html(players[currentNumber].description);
    // after you've decremented your index, check to see if you're at the beginning
    if (currentNumber == 0)
      // if you are, hide the previous button
      $(".btn-previous").hide();
    else {
      // if you aren't, update the previous button's text
      $(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name);
      // make sure the previous button is shown
      $(".btn-previous").show();
    }
    $(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);
  });

  // When a person clicks on the next button
  $(".btn-next").on("click", function() {
    currentNumber = currentNumber + 1;

    $(".btn-previous").show();
    $(".player__info--name").html(players[currentNumber].name);
    $(".player__info--desc").html(players[currentNumber].description);
    $(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name);
    if (currentNumber == (players.length - 1))
      // if at the end of your list, hide the next button
      $(".btn-next").hide();
    else {
      // if not, show the next button and update its text
      $(".btn-next").show();
      $(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);
    }
    $(".controls__inner").css("justify-content", "flex-start");
  });


});


var players = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "description": "description1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "description": "description2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name3",
    "description": "description3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "name4",
    "description": "description4"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "name5",
    "description": "description5"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "name6",
    "description": "description6"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "name7",
    "description": "description7"
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player__info">
  <div class="player__info--inner-group">
    <div class="player__image--wrapper">
      <div class="player__image"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- player__image--wrapper -->

    <div class="player__info--inner">
      <p class="player__info--header">Key Players</p>
      <p class="player__info--name">tk-name</p>

      <div class="player__info--group">
        <p class="player__info--desc"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- player__info--inner -->
  </div>
  <!-- player__info--inner-group -->
</div>
<!-- player__info -->

<div class="controls">
  <div class="controls__inner">
    <button class="btn btn-previous">Previous: <span class="is-bold">tk-name</span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-next">Next: <span class="is-bold">tk-name</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Added some comments to help explain.  Basically you want to check whether you're at the end of your range AFTER you update the current index.  If you're at the end, hide the respective button, if you're not at the end, show that button and update its contents.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I would like to hear about your logic / reasoning behind how you approached the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Added a few comments to give you a little more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're displaying the *Prev* and *Next* buttons when you're on player index 0 which result in trying to fetch the `players[0 - 1]` object.

The same thing happens with the last *Next* button which tries to get `players[6 + 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access indexes which do not exist in the array.

Once the value of `currentNumber + 1` is more than 6, `players[ 7 ]` will be undefined. Hence, the error.

Same for value of `currentNumber - 1` being less than 0.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet for how I could fix this problem.

Comment: You could wrap this line `$(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name);` in a if statement which checks for currentNumber being 0 `if(currentNumber){$(".btn-previous span").html(players[currentNumber - 1].name);}`, because you are making it 0 here `currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;` if currentNumber was 1 to start with. Same for the other case `$(".btn-next span").html(players[currentNumber + 1].name);`, you should wrap this in a if which checks for currentNumber !== 6.

Comment: @gargsms For efficient code reading I suggest you add that to the answer.